# How to insert an HTML code block in a WordPress blog post

Tags: html, wordpress, tags

I had written a blog post in WordPress and checked its preview before publishing and noticed a strange format change in the HTML code I have added in my blog post, converting (encoding) the < and > characters into their (&lt) and (&gt).

Is there a plugin I can add for displaying the code as it is?

Comment: See this -- https://lorelleteaches.com/2012/10/25/how-to-add-html-in-a-wordpress-blog-post/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a long research and help from my seniors, I got this solution for restricting the WordPress from converting (encoding) the `<` and `>` characters into their (&lt) and (&gt) equivalents:

You can use:

```
<pre class="lang:html decode:true ">
    /* Some HTML code here */
</pre>
```

Comment: Why a space after "true"? Is it required?

Comment: Not compulsory @PeterMortensen

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the `<` character with a special character `〈`, and the `>` character by `〉` just to prevent rendering my HTML code on my blog.