# HTML code formatting in WordPress with pre and code tags

Tags: html, wordpress

I have enclosed the HTML code in `<pre>` and `<code>` tags, but the code keeps getting changed to the following. How can I correct this?

```
[pre]
[code language="html"]
&amp;amp;amp;amp;lt;!DOCTYPE html&amp;amp;amp;amp;gt;
[/code]
[/pre]
```

Comment: Have you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42360595/how-to-insert-html-code-block-in-wordpress-blog-post?rq=1

Comment: Related: *[How to insert an HTML code block in a WordPress blog post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42360595)* - essentially adding attribute `class="lang:html decode:true"` to the `pre` tag.

Answer (score 2):

Try plugin [SyntaxHighlighter](https://wordpress.org/plugins/syntaxhighlighter/).

You can then write code like this:

```
[html]
/* Some HTML code */
[/html]
```